# Missing Folders in Solution Explorer Created by Project Solution in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, architecture, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a solution projects with different folders under the main `src` folder. The problem is, they are gone whenever I open the solution explorer of the solution project.

[image]

As you can see on the image, I properly created the folder `src` as the parent and Services and WebApps as the children folders. But they ended up missing on my solution explorer.

Answer (score 1):

These are solution folders, not physical folders on the file system. Solution folders are for the sake of solution organization, not physical organization.

In order to have physical folders on the file system, create them in e.g. File Explorer, move your projects there, and add them as necessary into your solution.

The advantage is that the physical (file system) and logical (solution folders) layout may be different, serving different purposes.

Comment: do you have some sample procedures sir?

Comment: Because I'm having a problem with the multiple .sln files